# In embedded design, what is the actual overhead of using a linux os vs programming directly against the cpu?

Tags: linux, embedded, arm, bare-metal

I understand that the answer to this question, like most, is "it depends", but what I am looking for is not so much an answer as much as a rationale for the different things affecting the decision.

My use case is that I have an ARM Cortex A8 (TI AM335x) running an embedded device. My options are to use some embedded linux to take advantage of some prebuilt drivers and other things to make development faster, but my biggest concern for this project is the speed of the device. Memory and disk space are not much of a concern. I think it is a safe assumption that programming directly against the mpu and not using a full OS would certainly make the application faster, but gaining a 1 or 2 percent speedup is not worth the extra development time.

I imagine that the largest slowdowns are going to come from the kernel context switching and memory mapping but I do not have the knowledge to correctly assess or gauge the extent of those slowdowns. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider: If you rewrite something to avoid the OS (e.g. drivers) your version might also perform worse than the kernel's.

Comment: Going without an OS, can and will reduce overhead and improve performance, but by how much?  it might be a minimal amount.  You have the factors of initial development and maintenance if you choose to go bare metal.  That also may or may not be a big deal depending on the device, existing code, etc.  I think you are going to have to just try it and see if you really want to know how much of an improvement you are going to get.

Comment: Well, what does it do, and what does it have?  If it's a washing-machine controller with 8K of RAM and 128K of flash, it's not gonna run linux all that well, TBH.

Comment: You imagine wrong. All the slowdown will come from finding out how to configure peripherals optimally

Comment: @auselen - that's a severely ignorant comment.  There are lots of "simple but fast" tasks for which an operating system is a real impediment - if one is going to also run an OS, the critical task ends up having to be moved out from under it, so as to either become part of the kernel, or even be run *above* the kernel.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "AM335x" in question is probably a BeagleBone Black. OP says "Memory and disk space are not much of a concern", so I assume OP will use them eventually. So you need to program them optimally, introduce caches for eMMC (disk), handle cpufreq, probably need to communicate with some external unit - which would boil down to handling interrupts efficiently. You'll end up with a small OS anyway. So just not calling a small OS doesn't change the fact that you need to do many responsibilities of an OS. I'm pretty sure you can configure Linux down to that spec.

Comment: @auselen - your are assuming one set of requirements, while completely dismissing the possibility of latency and overhead concerns, so I can only conclude you have no personal experience of projects where *conventional* use of an operating system becomes an obstacle to meeting such requirements.  That utterly unfounded certainty is what makes your comment ignorant.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Did you read the question? Again it is a soc based on Cortex-A8. You almost need an OS to drive AM335x anyway. OP isn't interested in %1-%2 improvement, and Linux doesn't add much more than that as overhead. OP didn't mention any hard latency requirement which in most cases would make Cortex-A8 out of consideration. It would really impress me if you claim that you use a single core cortex-a8 board without an OS for a real purpose. Please tell me. I am always open to learn from others.

Comment: @auselen - your lack of familiarity with the **range** of embedded systems is showing. For many tasks, linux may easily add 1000% or more of overhead to the *specific* critical task, precluding that application without notably loading the CPU.  And no, you don't need a complicated OS to configure the device for the range of possible uses - uBoot and similar manage to after all.  The problem is that you have made a blanket statement based on one set of assumptions which are unvalidated by the question, and thus ignorantly overlooked every real world possibility which does not match those.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you look carefully my comment about "imagining" comes after AM335x, so why do you think it is about a range of embedded systems (question being tagged ARM)? Can you tell me where Linux can add 10x overhead on a 600Mhz Cortex-A8? When you mean latency and overhead I don't see any possible clue in the question - a proven OS doesn't just add overhead as we know, and when OP says "Memory and disk space are not much of a concern" I don't think he will be trying to implement a network device with it. I don't think I'm understanding what you are trying to say in this regard, sorry.

Comment: Anything with tight timing requirements for interaction with external signals tends to suffer a huge magnification of latency and jitter when run under a conventional operating system kernel - your readiness to overlook that suggests you have never tried to build such a system, where it is the performance of *specific events* and not *overall speed* which is the critical metric.  And no, the selection of the board does not in any way preclude such use.  Because we do not know the problem the poster is trying to solve, we can only make general points, and not blanket declarations as you did.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You could write this as your first comment which would be much more meaningful, however OP doesn't state any signal processing application - a developer working on signal processing would mention that primarily right? No you just take the title of question, stretch it and assumed AM335x shouldn't have sub units to handle possible signal interaction cases gracefully (see AM335x PRU) working nicely with host cpu / Linux. I didn't build an oscilloscope out of 8-bit system so my embedded range is limited but I do work with arm's _application cpus_ daily and I know about such SOCs.

Comment: I'm not in any way shape or form talking about signal processing.  Rather the problem is that you apparently have a very limited awareness of the range of embedded systems tasks - many require extremely timely reaction to signals representing real world events.  And yes, others do not.  We don't know which the poster is contemplating (we cannot in any way infer that from the chosen platform), so we cannot make blanket statements about what issue will be most challenging.

Comment: @dabloons I saw a reference on TI if you are still looking for pointers. See
"No Operating System" under http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_Software_Design_Guide

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can call it I/O processing if you like -I just don't have the word for it- still OP doesn't mention that. OP doesn't say latency to respond to something anywhere. OP doesn't mention he is setting up an embedded system for a specific purpose. He mentions using drivers which implicitly should mean accessing peripherals. OP gives name of the SOC, which you can easily look up its properties. OP says "my biggest concern for this project is the speed of the device". Then I get to make the comment, "All the slowdown will come from finding out how to configure peripherals optimally".

Comment: OP doesn't specify their requirements at all - that's why its **completely inappropriate for you to make a blanket declaration** of where the challenge will be.  You simply do not know **which measure of speed** is important here - your obviously limited embedded experience shows in your inability to appreciate the types of "speed" which you have not personally faced as a requirement in the past.  Any experienced embedded engineer would demand clarification of the metric before making a recommendation, as most solutions are great by some measures and terrible by others.

Comment: @ChrisStratton OP says "I do not have the knowledge to correctly assess or gauge the extent of those slowdowns. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!" and I comment as much as I know which you find "inappropriate". Of course my experience is limited, is there an unlimited one? Why don't you just say I'm more experienced then you? But then I would expect such experienced guy to spend his energy describing the problem so I would understand. I have some experience with AM335x which just tells me handling all the peripherals optimally is just hard to get right and I say that, very simple.

Comment: The OP does have the knowledge to state their specific problem - which may turn out to either be driven by requirements within your experience, or outside of it.  Your mistake was in **assuming** the nature of the problem they are trying to solve, in a way that precluded the possibility of challenges beyond those you are personally familiar with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton nice answer, I mean it :) however to me your obvious logical fallacy is how you could possibly expect me to do otherwise? There's higher chance that this won't be a tougher problem as you claim just considering question's quality and you put lots of effort to counter prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concerns are reasonable.  Going bare metal can/will improve performance but it may only be a few percent improvement..."it depends".

Going bare metal for something that has fully functional drivers in linux but no fully functional drivers bare metal, will cost you development and possibly maintenance time, is it worth that to get the performance gain?

You have to ask yourself as well am I using the right platform, and/or am I using the right approach for whatever it is you want to do on that processor that you think or know is too slow.  Are you sure you know where the bottleneck is?  Are you sure your optimization is in the right place?

You have not provided any info that would give us a gut feel, so you have to go on your gut feel as to what path to take.  A different embedded platform (pros and cons), bare metal or operating system.  Linux or rtos or other.  One programming language vs another, one peripheral vs another, and so on and so on.  You wont actually know until you try each of these paths, but that can be and likely is cost and time prohibitive...

As far as the generic title question of os vs bare metal, the answer is "it depends".  The differences can swing widely, from almost the same to hundreds to thousands of times faster on bare metal.  But for any particular application/task/algorithm...it depends.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Things to consider. Thank you, this is very helpful.